# Access control in Airflow

Tags: airflow

i have a problem with airflow.

Does Admin creates variables and controls access to each variable for each user?

Example: admin create Variable `a, b` and user `userA, userB`

Does admin can create role that allow `userA`read, edit variable `a`, can't edit `b`  and  `userB` read, edit `B`, can't edit `a`

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

**Part 1**

As an admin you can create the following permissions [image].

So perhaps you can first ensure the users cannot delete Variables.

**Part 2**

If User A and only User A knows the Variable value. I would take advantage of a lesser-known Airflow feature to **mask sensitive fields**. I have provided 2 URLs for ways to approach this. So essentially the variable output will be masked, allowing User A to only know the answer. User B will see a variable exists however the value is masked. I believe you might also have to ensure you restrict CLI access.

[source a](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/mask-sensitive-values.html)
[source b](https://marclamberti.com/blog/variables-with-apache-airflow/#How_to_hide_the_value_of_a_variable)

**Part 3**

FYI - Airflow can automatically obfuscate any values when the variable name contains either *secret* or *password*. The check for this value is case-insensitive, so the value of a variable with a name containing SECRET will also be hidden.